# bouncycastle encrypted data send from midlet to servlet

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, midlet

I want to encrypt data in a midlet which to be sent to a servlet. I could encrypt data in midlet . I used bouncycastle. It worked perfectly(I could encrypt and decrypt well). Then I send the encrypted data to servlet. For just testing I simply used the same code(at    decrypting which I used in midlet) in servlet to decrypt. But now the problem is, the data is not recieved as the midlet sends.Encrypted data has been changed.  Here is sample  out put which I got. this is the out put after encrypting in midlet.  øâ˜¬Ë•T«üwÈÉÜA?.bHÂ¾eenter code here  but when I got this from servlet thought inputstream. printed result is:  ÃƒÂ¸ÃƒÂ¢
Ã‚Â˜Ã‚Â¬ÃƒÂ‹Ã‚Â•TÃ‚Â«ÃƒÂ¼wÃƒÂˆÃƒÂ‰ÃƒÂœAÃ‚Â?.bHÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â¾e  also has an exception

### javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher  This is how I send data to server from midlet:

```
        String serverResponse = "not send to server";
        HttpConnection connection = null;
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-                                                                                                                                                      1.0,Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
            connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
            DataOutputStream os = (DataOutputStream) connection.openDataOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Writing message is: " + msg);
            os.writeUTF(msg);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
```

---

and in the servlet here is how I got: inside processRequest method  -------------------------------------------------------------

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
        ServletInputStream sin = request.getInputStream();
        String str = "";

        while ((i = sin.read()) != -1) {
            ch = (char) i;
            str = str + ch;
        }
        str.trim();
        System.out.println("Received Stream From MIDlet  Encript data=" + str);
```

---

here is how I encrypt data using bouncycastle DES algorythm

public byte[] encrypt(String textToEnrypt, String keyString) {

```
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        //   return;
    }

    byte[] keyData = keyString.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, 0, keyData.length, "DES");

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        //  return;
    }

    int cypheredBytes = 0;

    byte[] inputBytes = null;
    try {
        inputBytes = textToEnrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
        inputBytes = textToEnrypt.getBytes();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        //return;
    }

    byte[] outputBytes = new byte[100];

    try {
        cypheredBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length,
                outputBytes, 0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        //return;
    }
    /*
    String str = new String(outputBytes, 0, cypheredBytes);
    buffer = str;
    System.out.println("Encrypted string = " + str);
     * */

    newResponse = new byte[cypheredBytes];

    for (int i = 0; i < cypheredBytes; i++) {

        newResponse[i] = outputBytes[i];

    }

    buffer=new String(newResponse);
    System.out.println("Encripted text is:"+buffer);
    return newResponse;
}

public void decrypt(String textToDecrypt, String keyString) {
    Cipher cipher;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        return;
    }

    byte[] keyData = keyString.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, 0, keyData.length, "DES");

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("2. " + ex.toString());
        return;
    }

    int cypheredBytes = 0;

    byte[] inputBytes;
    try {
        inputBytes =textToDecrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
       inputBytes = textToDecrypt.getBytes();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("3. " + ex.toString());
        return;
    }

    byte[] outputBytes = new byte[100];

    try {
        cypheredBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length,
                outputBytes, 0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("4. " + ex.toString());
        return;
    }

    String str = new String(outputBytes, 0, cypheredBytes);
    System.out.println("Decrypted string = " + str);
}
```

---

I am new for these things. I got these codes from in this site as well. Please let me know how to get data in servelet as the midlet sends.(Without changing data.. ) if you see some error in my code or the way try to get.. pleas let me know with code sample. or else if there is an working sample code anywhere else to send data from midlet to servlet, let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is at least one possible culprit:

```
while ((i = sin.read()) != -1) {
    ch = (char) i;
    str = str + ch;
}
```

Why are you trying to turn opaque binary data (*not* text data) into a string? You're then calling `String.getBytes()` elsewhere to get binary data, without even specifying the encoding. **Don't do this.**

If you absolutely *have* to represent opaque binary data as text, use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). However, 
I see no reason for using text to transfer the data in the first place - just transmit it in binary to start with.

Additionally, to convert the text to binary data *before* encryption (near the start of `encrypt`), you should specify the encoding (UTF-8 is probably a good bet). Use the same encoding after you've decrypted the binary data, and want to convert the result back into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says: "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher".  You need to specify the same padding at both ends, encryption and decryption.  A common padding is PKCS#5, which should be available at both ends.  Don't rely on defaults, but specify the padding explicitly.  Different systems may have different defaults.

John's advice on not mixing text and bytes is excellent.

Comment: Thank you. But I am still new for these things.Would you let me know with a sample code please?

Comment: I am not an expert in BouncyCastle.  Have a look at the `crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding` class.  PKCS7 is effectively the same as PKCS5.  Add the padding to your plaintext before encrypting and remove it after decrypting.